# QTableView does not display data from QSqlTableModel using PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, pyside6

I have already found similar problems on the net, unfortunately the offered solutions did not work for me.

I'm trying to display tabular data from an SQLite database via the QTableView. The connection to the database seems to work in principle (I was able to query via QSql - so the database is not empty and the connection is established).

I've tried to include the database connection into the **init** method of the MainWindow before instantiating the QSqlModel. That had no effect. I also tried passing my database connection as an argument when instantiating the QSqlModel. That didn't do anything either.

So somehow my Model doesn't know anything about my database, but I have no more ideas what it could be.

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6 import QtSql
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("Names")
        self.model.select()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    db_connection = QtSql.QSqlDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db_connection.setDatabaseName("test_db.db")

    if not db_connection.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            "App Name - Error!",
            "Database Error: %s" % db_connection.lastError().databaseText(),
        )
        sys.exit(1)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Change to `db_connection = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")`.

Comment: Well, that did the trick! Thank you so much @musicamante! I was comparing the code over and over with other examples, but somehow missed that subtle difference. Now I am wondering though why I was able to perform a database query using just `QtSql.QSqlDatabase("QSQLITE")` while this was not enough to tell my model that there was a functioning connection?